# Best pratice to build JOINS in PHP OO

Tags: php, oop, join, model, conventions

Suppose that I have two tables, **Group** and **Item**.

An **Item** belong to one **Group**, that can have many Items.

Assuming the MVC pattern and that each table has his model class, with CRUD methods, written in PHP, what is the best practice to build a join, between **Item** and **Group**?

1. Build a `SELECT` statement in **Group** to get the ID of **Group** and then build a simple `SELECT` statement, using the gotten ID?

   ```
   /* Select by name in database and returns group object with id and name */
   $group = new Group();
   $group->setName('somename');
   $group->selectByname(); 


   $item = new Group();
   /* Sets Group object inside Item */
   $item->setGroup($group);

   /* Select statement without join, only comparing id */
   /* SELECT FROM Item WHERE group_id = $group->id */
   $item->selectByGroup();
   ```
2. ...or build the JOIN directly on Item class?

   ```
   /* Sets the name, returning only the name in the Group object */
   $group = new Group();
   $group->setName('somename');

   /* Build the JOIN inside Item class */
   $item = new Item();
   $item->setGroup($group);

   /* Select statetment with join */
   /* SELECT it.*, gr.* FROM item it INNER JOIN group gr
      ON it.group_id = gr.id
      WHERE gr.name = $group->name 
   */
   $item->selectByGroupWithJoin();
   ```

Some parts of the code I just ommited or simplified to help to explain my doubt.

So what is the recommended/best practice? If not one of these, what other? Thanks.

Comment: OOP is for decomposing systems into networks of interacting state machines. MVC is a UI pattern separating the UI state, appearance and interaction. Neither is a data modeling discipline nor meant for implementing and managing navigational databases.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand it correctly, in the first case you have to perform two queries while in the second one only one, so I would definitely go with the second one.

In any case, you can always use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to get an estimate on how "heavy" your query is and where you have room for optimizations/improvements.

Comment: That is half of the answer that I'm searching. Besides the database factor, is this the best approach when talking of Object Oriented PHP programming?